# How to compile twice?

Tags: java, maven

I have a web service project where:

- In `src/main/precode`, I have Java classes I write manually and that I use to generate a WSDL file using `cxf-java2ws-plugin` plugin.
- In `src/main/java`, I have the final classes that I generate from the WSDL using `cxf-codegen-plugin` plugin.

The problem is that to generate the WSDL, it seems that the `cxf-java2ws-plugin` needs compiled classes, so I have to execute the plugin after the compile phase. So, I also need to execute the `cxf-codegen-plugin` after the compile phase, since it needs the WSDL file generated by the other plugin.
But, in order to compile my SEI (i.e. before the compile phase), I need the classes generated by the `cxf-codegen-plugin`, so I'm stuck.

I've thought about splitting this into two projects but I'm looking for a one project solution. I think that if there was a possibility to compile twice, it would solve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every execution of a plugin, adds to the `phase` in the order they are declared.

```
pluginA:exectionA:compile
pluginC:exectionA:compile
pluginB:exectionA:compile
```

Would generate a `compile` with the default definition `<sourceDirectory></sourceDirectory> (src/main/java )` plus the execution of `A, C and B`.

Just by adding the execution of the `maven-compiler-plugin` with the appropriate `<configuration>` in `compile` right after the declaration of the `cxf-java2ws-plugin` plugin (which is also bound to `compile`).

In the `pom.xml` add the  directory to:

```
<sourceDirectory></sourceDirectory>
Element : sourceDirectory
3.0.0+
This element specifies a directory containing the source of the 
 project. The generated build system will compile the source in 
 this directory when the project is built. The path given is 
 relative to the project descriptor.`
```

You can also configure the `compiler plugin`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand how it solves the problem? During which phase each plugin should be executed?

Comment: The cxf-java2ws-plugin must be executed before the cxf-codegen-plugin. So, the execution phase of the cxf-java2ws-plugin must appear before the execution phase of the cxf-codegen-plugin. And, both phases must appear before the "compile" phase since I need the generated classes to compile my implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the cxf maven plugins so getting the input and output directories for the plugin executions configured correctly is up to you.  With that said, here's how I'd attempt this (untested!).

- Add an execution to the compiler plugin config to run the `compile` goal.  Bind this execution to the `generate-sources` phase (for lack of anything better).  Execution ID should be something like "precode-compile".  Use the `<includes>` parameter for compile goal to specify the `/src/main/precode` directory as the input.
- Configure the `cxf-java2ws-plugin` to run during the `process-sources` phase, using the classes generated in the above step as input.
- Configure the `cxf-codegen-plugin` to also run during the `process-sources` phase, specifying the WSDL as input.  Make sure to have this config after the java2ws plugin config, as goals bound to the same phase run in the order they are defined in the POM.

If I'm understanding your use case correctly, I think the default compile goal (execution ID "default-compile") bound is now okay where it is.  If I didn't quite understand, at least you have ideas for things to try.

If you're not sure how to configure multiple executions for a single plugin, have a look in the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html).